# discord.py embed footer with timestamp

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

So I am trying to make something like this:
[image]

**Here is my current code:**

```
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
embed.set_footer(text = time, icon_url = "https://i.imgur.com/uZIlRnK.png")
```

**But it shows this:**
[image]

So how can I change the time of the second image like that of the first image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`Embed.timestamp`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.timestamp) which takes a `datetime.datetime` object.

You have two ways to add it

**First way:**

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='test',timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
embed.set_footer(text='\u200b',icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/uZIlRnK.png")
```

**Second way:**

```py
embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
embed.set_footer(text='\u200b',icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/uZIlRnK.png")
```

Note: `\u200b` is just a empty line.

**EDIT:**

Added footer icon.

Comment: That's for timestamp but then the footer feature won't work

Comment: @DriftAsimov Please check the edited code above. You have to add some text for the icon to appear I added a empty line which will not show anything.

Comment: Oh for me, your answer didn't update, thanks for the code, it works!

Comment: Good to hear that, please mark it as accepted answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use **datetime.datetime.now()** so it will show the time in the local time of all of the users.